# How to customize the header of the CSV file that exported by a SSRS report

Tags: csv, reporting-services

I have created an SSRS report and exported that to a CSV file. The header of that CSV file displays an odd name  *"Donations_Chart1_CategoryGroup_label"*.

I want to customize the name. If any one have an idea about that please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the header is taken from the `DataElementName` property, which can be set in the Properties Window, under "Data Only".

If it is not specified, the `Name` property is taken, it is autogenerated unless you change it, which explains your "odd name".

So you could either change the `Name` or the `DataElementName` of the element.

Comment: Thanks regarding your reply Sevrin.. I just want to customize column headers in my CSV file. My column names are displayed as an odd name like "Donations_Chart1_CategoryGroup_label".Eg: I want to replace that odd column header as "Average".

Comment: @user3796885 - Then you can set the `DataElementName` to "Average".